# Flutter test doesn't work in debug mode for a web application

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have build a web application with Flutter and also have some automatic tests that I am running normally with `flutter test --platform chrome`. When launching the tests with this command everything works fine.

Sometimes some test are not running green and I want to check what the error is. Debugging is in this case very helpful. The problem here is that I can't run the debug mode for my test because I need packages like `dart:html` for my code. When running the tests on chrome everything works, but for the debug mode that I can start in VS Code by clicking next to the test on the start icon, the tests don't start and show errors like

```
Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
```

Is there a way to change the config of the debug button in test files so I can start them on chrome or is there any other workaround, so I can debug my tests that rely on web packages?